# How to let Vim process my command backforward?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have 5 lines of text, if I input some commands to let vim process each line, Vim will process the text one by one, first line, second line, ... the last line. what I want is to let Vim process my text in reverse order. that is the last line first, then the 4th line, and at last the first line.

Why I need this?
I have the following text

```
1234567890
abc
123
def
1234567890
123456789
```

I want to remove the newline symbol(\n) from lines which contains 3 characters. so after processing，I will get the following text

```
1234567890
abc123def1234567890
123456789
```

It seems a piece of cake, I use the following command

```
:%s/\v(^\w{3})\n/\1/
```

But what i got is

```
1234567890
abc123
def1234567890
1234567890
```

Why? I guess vim first remove \n from the second line, then this line has text abc123, now vim will not remove \n after 123, since it's not 3 characters now, so vim process the next line def, and remove \n from it, that's the result i got.

If vim can process from back to front, this will not happen and I can got the result I want.

BTW, I can get the expected result in other ways, I just want to know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly loop over the range of lines (e.g. the visually selected ones) backwards, then execute the command on each line. I've used `:join` here instead of the `:substitute` with a newline:

```
:for i in range(line("'>"), line("'<"), -1)| silent execute i . 'g/^\w\{3}$/join!' | endfor
```

Comment: Huh? I don't see anything in there that would prevent successful use in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved using perl:

```
while (<>) {
  chomp if (/^...$/);
  print;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use perl, just Vim.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is easier to use the `:global` command to join the lines.

```
:g/^\w\{3}$/normal! gJ
```

The command `gJ` joins the current line with the following line without inserting any spaces. The global command above calls `gJ` on each line containing only three characters. It works by marking all the matches first, before performing the operation, so the problem of looping is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

this line should do what you want:

```
:%s/\v(\_^\w{3}\n)+/\=substitute(submatch(0),"\n","","g")/
```

if you want to do it simpler with external command, e.g. awk, you could:

```
%!awk '{printf "\%s", length($0)==3? $0:$0"\n"}'
```